# How do i update my mapbox markers when the geojson data is passed in as props in a vue component

Tags: vue.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, ionic-vue

#### Edit 1

Here is the source code on [git](https://github.com/nvispute/Ionic-vue-6-Mapbox-GL/tree/master/src)

I am working on an Ionic-Vue project with Mapbox integration. My issue is that I am unable to update my geojson data source to create markers on the map, the geoJson data is passed in as props. Here is the flow

***On APP.vue created hook***

1. Using capacitor gets user current location.
2. .then() make an Axios call to the server to fetch the JSON data

   - On success set the data to store via mutation

***On Home.vue[parent component for TheMap.vue]***

1. Computed value called `getGeoJson` which calls the getters to get geojson data from the state saved an earlier step
2. Bind the `:marker` prop with computed value `getGeoJson` data on the TheMap component to be sent as a prop.
3. Listen to the event `$updatedLocation` and call the API action to fetch new geojson data.

***On TheMap.vue***

1. On create Hook call the `createMap()`.
2. In Method: `createMap()`

   - Get the user coords again using `capacitorJS`
   - init the mapbox map and save it to `this.map` variable
   - add Attribution using `this.map.addControl`
   - `this.map.on("load",cb)`  inside of cb call `.addSource()` & then `addMarkers()`
   - Create a new `marker` for the current user and save it to cosnt `UserLocationMarker`
   - `UserLocationMarker.on("dragend",CB)` to emit a event with latest current user location

Here is the code for the same just putting the script tags rather than the whole.vue file

`APP.Vue`

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      currentLocation: "",
    };
  },
  created() {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
      .then((result) => {
        this.currentLocation = [
          result.coords.longitude,
          result.coords.latitude,
        ];
        this.$store.dispatch(
          `lists/${POST_GEOJSON_ACTION}`,
          this.currentLocation
        );
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  },
};
```

`Home.vue`

```
<template>
   <the-map :markers="geojson" @updatedLocation="updateMap"></the-map>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Home",
  computed: {
    getGeoJson() {
      return this.$store.getters[`lists/${GET_GEOJSON_GETTER}`];
    },
  },
  methods: {
    updateMap(center) {
      this.$store.dispatch(`lists/${POST_GEOJSON_ACTION}`, center);
    },
  },
};

</script>
```

`TheMap.vue`

```
export default {
  props: ["markers"],
  emits: ["updatedLocation"],
  data() {
    return {
      access_token: process.env.VUE_APP_MAP_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      center: [0, 0],
      map: {},
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.createMap();
  },
  methods: {
    async createMap() {
      try {
        const coords = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
        this.center = [coords.coords.longitude, coords.coords.latitude];
        mapboxgl.accessToken = this.access_token;

        //Map Instance
        this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
          container: "map",
          style: "mapbox://styles/userName/API_KEY",
          center: this.center,
          zoom: 12,
          scrollZoom: true,
        });

        // Custom Attribution over the map for Branding
        this.map.addControl(
          new mapboxgl.AttributionControl({
            customAttribution: ` &#169; Comapny Name`,
          })
        );

        this.map.on("load", function(e) {
          this.map.addSource("places", {
            type: "geojson",
            data: this.markers,
          });
          this.addMarkers();
        });

        const UserLocationMarker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
          draggable: true,
        })
          .setLngLat(this.center)
          .addTo(this.map);

        UserLocationMarker.on("dragend", async (e) => {
          this.center = Object.values(e.target.getLngLat());
          this.$emit("updatedLocation", this.center);
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    },

    addMarkers() {
      this.markers.features.forEach(function(marker) {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.id = "marker-" + marker.properties.id;
        el.className = "marker";
        new mapboxgl.Marker(el, { offset: [0, -23] })
          .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
          .addTo(this.map);
      });
    },
  },
};
```

My issue here is that the `TheMap.vue` does get `undefined` | `[{geojson}]` as a prop however it does not load the marker on init or even after the source is changed in the parent component.

What I expect is that the map on Load uses markers prop to build a list of markers if available else show nothing[handle `undefined |` null`] And update that marker list if a new set of Data is injected as prop on changed location.

Comment: Can you provide more info/code of the `lists/${POST_GEOJSON_ACTION}` action and the `lists/${GET_GEOJSON_GETTER}` getter?

Comment: @Andy these are regular vuex actions & getters..

Comment: @Andy I have added git repo for the same